# Change layout direction of flexed boxes reliably

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm trying to achieve the following layout changes with css3 only. My main problem here is, that I don't want to add sizes explicitly. I'd prefer to let the layout flow freely. I'm using the css `flexbox`. And after an automatic *wrap* the layout direction of the small items should change.

[image]
[image]

I made this behavior almost work with `@media(orientation: portrait)`. But then I still have restrictions on the size of the red box. You find that there's a third state with the yellow items being displayed horizontally next to the red box.

```css
div {
  min-width: 50px;
  min-height: 50px;
  margin: 8px;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

#body {
  background: lightgray;
  padding: 8px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#box {
  background: lightpink;
  min-width: 150px;
  height: 220px;
  flex-grow: 1;
}

.item {
  background: lightyellow;
}

#wrap {
  margin: 0;
}

@media(orientation: portrait) {
  #wrap {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: flex-end;
  }
}
```

```html
<title>Example</title>
<div id="body">
  <div id="box"></div>
  <div id="wrap">
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Please not that all sizes are purely superficial.*

I was wondering if it's possible to force the item box to wrap when the *landscape* mode is active. Or maybe have a selector for the red box filling the complete horizontal viewport.

Comment: Not sure if this will help  https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/3pfqfyqm/6/ .

Comment: Makes it better for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a `display:block` on the div with id `body` and add this in your media rule

```
@media(orientation: portrait) {
#wrap { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: flex-end;border:solid red;}
#body{display:block;}
}
```

[fiddle here with resizable window](https://jsfiddle.net/repzeroworld/3pfqfyqm/6/) else

snippet

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style type="text/css">
div { min-width: 50px; min-height: 50px; margin: 8px; justify-content: flex-end; }
#body { background: lightgray; padding: 8px; display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; }
#box { background: lightpink; min-width: 150px; height: 220px; flex-grow: 1; }
.item { background: lightyellow; }
#wrap { margin: 0;border:solid green; }
#break{}
@media(orientation: portrait) {
#wrap { display: flex; flex-wrap: wrap; justify-content: flex-end;border:solid red;}
#body{display:block;}
}
</style>
<title>Example</title>
<div id="body">
<div id="box"></div>
<div id="wrap">
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
<div class="item"></div>
</div></div>
```